# Avoid checking passwords for dos attacks

Tags: authentication, ddos, checksum

A server gets requests with a username and password. Checking the password can be expensive, so a hacker can do a DoS attack by sending lots of requests with random  passwords. No attempt to break in, just trying to waste time on the server.

Would it be safe to store a CRC32 checksum of the correct password per username, so the huge majority of random password guesses can be rejected with very little effort? Especially if the rejection is delayed, so an attacker cannot know whether they got the checksum right?

Comment: Are you asking about replacing a cryptographically secure hash with a CRC32 code? If not, how would you implement what you suggest? Can you please provide more details?

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be safe to store a CRC32 checksum of the correct password per username, so the huge majority of random password guesses can be rejected with very little effort?

No, it would not be safe. [CRC codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) are not meant to be [cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). It's much [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517776) to find [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision) with CRCs rather than with cryptographically secure hashes. Also, in case that an attacker gets hold of your db, it would be much easier to retrieve the passwords by brute forcing the CRC32 hashes than if you used a strong [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). The reason is that a key derivation function is by design expensive (CPU/RAM) to execute, which makes brute forcing passwords a very resource demanding process; on the other hand, CRC codes do not have this feature.

If you wanted to actually replace the password hashes with the CRC codes, then in this [article](https://eklitzke.org/crcs-vs-hash-functions) you'll find a quick explanation on why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: *"use CRC codes in place of cryptographically secure hashes"* - that's not what the OP is trying from my understanding. It is not about replacing the existing password hash but about augmenting it with a CRC32, so that a right password must be a match both for the (insecure) CRC32 and for the secure password hash.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich hm... "so an attacker cannot know whether they got the checksum right": I interpreted this as asking if it would be safe to replace the secure password hash. I asked for clarifications

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I elaborated my answer to address your comment

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you are trying to do a two step verification of the password: first a cheap verification against a CRC32 which will filter out many password attempts quickly but still match some wrong passwords. Then the more expensive real password check to find out if the password passing CRC32 is also the expected password.

The problem with this approach is that you must assume that the expected CRC32 can leak the same way as the "real" robust password hash can leak.
A good password hash must provide its high use of resources (time, memory) for every entered password, no matter if it is a valid one or not. By adding CRC32 you instead created essentially a password hash which is cheap and fast for wrong passwords but expensive for right passwords - thus allowing a brute force attack to quickly skip over the majority of the wrong passwords.

Comment: It's even worse than that, too. CRC32 isn't secure against predictable modifications the way a secure hash algorithm is. An attacker who knows most of a password - perhaps a common base string that the user incorporates in lots of passwords - can potentially figure out the rest by comparing the CRC32 of the partial password to the (leaked) CRC32 of the real password, and derive the missing part without needing to brute force anything. It could also be used to determine the entire possible range of candidate passwords out to a given length, before attempting any brute-force search at all.

Answer (score 0):

Safe is not an absolute given. If you are absolutely sure that no-one will ever be able to access your database of CRCs, then it would probably be OK. However, once the CRC32s are compromised, you reduce the complexity for finding passwords significantly.

If, instead of a CRC32, you would use only a simple parity-bit, you would still reduce the quantity of checks significantly, and the information in your password-parity database is not all that valuable. Note, that it will also reduce the amount of time to bute-force passwords by 50% if the password-parity database gets stolen.

So, as so often in security, it's a trade-off. You could increase the minimal password size by 1 character, and use a 4 bit checksum, for example.